# Is Oracle gathering information from my machine when I download Virtualbox or Netbeans?

Tags: privacy, oracle

When we try to download Netbeans or Virtualbox from the Oracle/Sun site, our firewall warns us that some suite called EdgeSuite tries to obtain information from our machines. I don't know what information it is gathering, but I can't download any of them because our firewall categorizes its actions as a violation of privacy.

Is the firewall correct?  Does Oracle gather information from your machine when you download Netbeans or Virtualbox?
If yes, what information is gathered?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place either.  I'd suggest contacting Sun/Oracle.  A Wiki search for EdgeSuite points to the Akamai Technologies article:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5056061#5056061

Comment: I agree with Iszi: start by contacting Oracle.  You might also check the Oracle privacy policy.

Answer (score 1):

EdgeSuite (sub-domains of edgesuite.net) is a service of Akamai : http://www.akamai.com.
Many important companies use Akamai & EdgeSuite network capabilities to host files : Sun/Oracle, Apple, Adobe, etc.
Take it as a mirror site with high network capabilities ;)

Does it try to get information about your computer?

If you download products via your browser via HTTP or FTP: the server won't be able to get a lot of informations, only what your browser exhibits (browser's codename, OS name, ...).

Comment: But note that the browser actually exhibits quite a lot: see [Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).

Comment: All the links fo Akamai that uses this !@#$ EdgeSuite are blocked inside my organization (university) because of a firewall rule. So it try to take more information than any other site. Therefor it's still a disrespect.

Comment: It doesn't take more informations than any other website. Your network admin (or the proxy/security software) probably thinks EdgeSuite is a download site. So, he black-listed this domain to preserve your university Internet bandwidth ;)

If your admin is intelligent, he will be able to understand it is a legit website.